# MySQL Get val with max(date) along with sum

Tags: mysql

Here's my problem. I have a table with the following columns:

```
player_id | win_amount | loss_amount | datetime
```

Every record holds the player's id, the win or loss amount (the other field goes to  0) and the datetime.
I want a MySQL query to get the following:

- `player_id`
- `sum(win_amount) - sum(loss_amount)` of that player
- last datetime where there is a non-zero `loss_amount`
- the `loss_amount` of the previous datetime

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself yet?  If so, can you include some sample data along with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query, utilizing `GROUP BY`, some aggregate functions and [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html). Replace `table` with your actual table name:

```
SELECT 
    t1.player_id,
    SUM(t1.win_amount) - SUM(t1.loss_amount) AS net_win_amount,
    MAX(IF(t1.loss_amount > 0,
        t1.datetime,
        NULL)) AS last_loss_datetime,
    (SELECT 
            t2.loss_amount
        FROM
            `table` AS t2
        WHERE
            t2.player_id = t1.player_id
                AND t2.loss_amount > 0
        ORDER BY t2.datetime DESC
        LIMIT 0 , 1) AS last_loss_amount
FROM
    `table` AS t1
GROUP BY t1.player_id
```